# How to combine multiple lines of paragraph in html into one?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a html file having headers and paragraphs of a pdf file. But in this file every line of paragraph is considered as another paragraph and thats why it is giving many

tags lines, so it is not possible to create a single paragraph of multiple lines. Can anyone suggest me a way to solve this?.

This is way I am getting:

```
["<p>Forti provides access to a diverse array of Forti solutions through a single sign-on ",
  "<p>including Forti Cloud, Forti Cloud, Forti, Forti, Forti and other Forti ",
  "<p>cloud-based management and services. Forti accounts are free which require a license for ",
  "<p>each solution. "]
```

where as I want it in this way:

```
['Forti provides access to a diverse array of Forti solutions through a single sign-on including Forti Cloud, FortiWeb Cloud, Forti, Forti, Forti and other Forti cloud-based management and services. Forti accounts are free which require a license for each solution. ']
```

I have done this :

```
paragraphs_1 = []
local_path = "file.json"
data = json.loads(open(local_path).read())
for x in data:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser') 
    for paragraphs in soup.find_all("p"): 
        paragraphs_1.append(paragraphs.get_text())
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use replace function to get rid of all p...like

```
yourtext.replace("<p>", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
new_list = []
for text in my_list_of_text:
    # first remove <p>
    new_list.append(text.replace('<p>', ''))
# next step create a long text using list comprehension
listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in new_list]) 
# remove possible double space
final_text= listToStr.replace('  ', ' ')
```

There is more sophisticated manner using simplenlg for example. But for your problem this code should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The below function helps to clean `raw_html` tags

```
import re

def cleanhtml(raw_html):
  cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
  cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_html)
  return cleantext
```

If you want to combine multiple elements in list and return it as a single paragraph, you can try `.join()`

```
paragraph = cleanhtml(str(''.join(para)))
```

**Output:**

```
'Forti provides access to a diverse array of Forti solutions through a single sign-on including Forti Cloud, Forti Cloud, Forti, Forti, Forti and other Forti cloud-based management and services. Forti accounts are free which require a license for each solution. '
```

or

to return it as list

```
paragraph = [cleanhtml(str(''.join(para)))]
```

**Output**

```
['Forti provides access to a diverse array of Forti solutions through a single sign-on including Forti Cloud, Forti Cloud, Forti, Forti, Forti and other Forti cloud-based management and services. Forti accounts are free which require a license for each solution. ']
```